# Wired animation during page curl segue

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I can't quite believe this is just me, but I can't find this anywhere!

I have a UIViewController setup in my storyboard, I've added a button that calls a segue to another UIViewController.  The segue is set to use the page curl animation.

This all works as expected - except the text in the UIButtons on the view that is revealed animates into place.  The text starts on the right hand side of each button and stretchs out to fill the button.

I also have a UISegmentedControl, this whole control start with 0 width on the left hand side and stretches to the designed width.

By the time the page curl animation is over the controls are in the state I drew them on the storyboard.

I have played around with the auto-re-sizing within the storyboard, but to no success!

? - Thanks